# Условие в исключении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Могу ли я создать условие в исключении?
Имеем код

```py
except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError as ex: 
    if ex == "[15] Access denied: this profile is private":
        print("Yes")
    else:
        pass
    break
```

Comment: Что мешает сделать и проверить?

Comment: Имеется ввиду можно Лив else добавить другое условие?

Comment: В моем виде просто не сработало

Comment: Так `pass` просто ничего не делает, это бесполезное `else`. Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Чтобы выполнялось условие. При появлении ошибки [15]. 
При остальных пропуск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можете. При сравнении преобразовывайте ошибку в строку

```
except Exception as er:
    error_message = str(er) 
    expected_error = "[15] Access denied: this profile is private"
    if error_message == expected_error:
        ...
```

Comment: Как я понимаю в моем случает приобретает вид:
`except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError as ex:
    error_message = str(ex) 
    expected_error = "[15] Access denied: this profile is private"
    if error_message == expected_error:
        print("Yes")
    else:
          pass
break `

Comment: да, но без break

Comment: спасибо! помогло, но break нужен был
Без него цикл в 50 сообщений, а этого не нужно